# Is there a name for a non-ambiguous statement that contains unresolved ambiguous details?

Tags: terminology, ambiguity, disambiguities

Yearless dates can be ambiguous.  "04/07" for instance is understood as "April 7" by Americans, but as "the 4<sup>th</sup> of July" by most other nationalities.
This ambiguity is frequently resolved by the context it was written in, but often not.

I recently wrote something using this date format, saw that it would be ambiguous, and then immediately realized that it didn't matter.
The two dates were individually ambiguous, but together they weren't:

> Each year, 05/09 and 09/05 fall on the same weekday.

It doesn't matter whether one reads these as MM/DD or as DD/MM; the sentence is equally correct, even though the two dates each remain ambiguous.

Is there a name for this phenomenon of ambiguous details that together produce a non-ambiguous result?

Comment: It's nevertheless ambiguous because it remains ambiguous whether it says "May 9 and September 5" or it says "5 September and 9 May." Any happenstance the ambiguity ends up not mattering in the end doesn't resolve the ambiguity in the statement as to exactly which of those things the statement says. What's more, it's conceivable that the order in which the dates are presented does in some way matter, meaning stating the statement is unambiguous despite the unresolved details contained therein may be not just untrue but also presumptuous.

Comment: Other than with inconsequentially ambiguous (I'd say your example isn't) examples ("Your 'hurricane' may not be my 'hurricane' "), I can't see the potential for many examples. I'd suspect there isn't a name, at least in general English. Perhaps there is an overlapping concept in set theory.

Comment: Even if we accept that your example's denoted meaning is unambiguous overall by way of the happenstance that interpreting "May 9 and September 5" or "5 September and 9 May" is interpreting the same data set and by presuming order makes no difference, your example's connoted meaning remains ambiguous overall since "May 9 and September 5" would connote the meaning that it was written by an American and/or for Americans, whereas "5 September and 9 May" would connote the meaning that it wasn't, authorship and audience not being insignificant connotative meaning since they color...

Comment: ...credibility (actual and perceived), purpose (actual and perceived), readership, importance, and more. Also, the meaning "May 9 and September 5" is in chronological order and compliant with standards set by style guides, while "5 September and 9 May" is in nonchronological order and noncompliant with standards set by style guides, unless there's a meaningful purpose for listing them nonchronologically, like to rank 5 September as more important, connotatively meaning the writer is writing informally or ignorantly nonstandard or is conveying an inequality between 5 September and 9 May.

Comment: This coincidence is probably extremely rare and also not very interesting linguistically, so there's little point in naming it. Maybe if you posted in [linguistics.se] someone would come up a clever neologism for it.